Unable to use local resource with vscode-resource

Version: 1.92.0 (user setup)
b1c0a14de1414fcdaa400695b4db1c0799bc3124
Commit: 2024-07-31T23:26:45.634Z
Electron: 30.1.2
Chromium: 124.0.6367.243
Node.js: 20.14.0
V8: 12.4.254.20-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631

The component uses lazy loading and cannot request local resources.
Page routing information.
import { lazy } from 'react'
import type { RouteObject } from 'react-router-dom';

const BbbEditor = lazy(
  () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "bbb-editor'"*/ '@/views/editor/bbb-editor/bbb-editor'),
);
const { editor } = routes;
const editorRoutes: readonly RouteObject[] = [
  {
    path: editor.bbbEditor.path,
    element: <BbbEditor />,
  },
];

index-mvF9e7MR.js:75 
       GET vscode-webview://1ndcb0cu2feq505fifvmhf465gi9or6gv0tabf92jinh4uhu0kgk/static/js/bbb-editor-BWC71SfP.js net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED

I hope that the component can use lazy loading and can also request local resources.
